# Carry forward value across columns based on condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a longitudinal data like below:

```
structure(list(ID = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102), 
               `A` = c(7, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
               `B` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5), 
               `C` = c(NA, 7, 0, NA, 0, 0), 
               `D` = c(7, NA, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
               `Cycle` = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I want to use carry-forward method to replace values across A B and C. The condition is: if in prior cycle, the value is 7, then replace the values with 7 in following cycles. For example, person 101 has value 7 in variable A in cycle 1, so replace the values with 7 in cycle 2 and 3 for the same variable in same person.

The data I would like to generate:

```
structure(list(ID = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102), 
               `A` = c(7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0), 
               `B` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5), 
               `C` = c(NA, 7, 7, NA, 0, 0), 
               `D` = c(7, 7, 7, 1, 0, 1), 
               `Cycle` = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with `mutate` (or other functions)?

Modified: new dataset as below.

```
structure(list(ID = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 
103, 104, 104, 104, 108, 108, 108, 122, 122, 122, 123, 123), 
    `7B` = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 8, 0, NA, 9, 0, NA, 8, 
    0, NA, 8, 0, NA, 8), `7M` = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 8, 
    0, NA, 9, 0, NA, 8, 0, NA, 8, 0, NA, 8), `7L` = c(NA, 0, 
    0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 8, 2, 5, 7, 0, NA, 8, 0, NA, 8, 0, NA, 8
    ), `7D` = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 8, 0, 1, 7, 0, NA, 8, 
    0, NA, 8, 0, NA, 8), `7O` = c(NA, 11, 11, NA, 0, 1, NA, 
    8, 11, 11, 7, 5, NA, 8, 0, NA, 8, 5, NA, 8), `6B` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `6M` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), `6L` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 
    0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `6D` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), visit = c(1, 2, 3, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: So do you still want to carry forward 7, or the value is now different? Do you want to do it by maximum value of each column? Max of each column by group? Can you also post your desired output for the modified dataset? Both of the solutions provided below still work for the modified dataset as well. Try running them in a fresh session of R.

Comment: @M-- still value 7. That's why initially I created a sample data. My original data is really big and 7 is not very common. It's hard for me to find a case with ideal value distribution . But the added sample is exactly part of my data. Unfortunately the carry-forwrd function still doesn't work. But your solution seems work in this new dataset! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::cumany`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(A:D, ~if_else(cumany(replace_na(.x, 0) == 7), 7, .x)), .by = ID)

#>    ID A B  C D Cycle
#> 1 101 7 0 NA 7     1
#> 2 101 7 0  7 7     2
#> 3 101 7 1  7 7     3
#> 4 102 0 0 NA 1     1
#> 5 102 0 0  0 0     2
#> 6 102 0 5  0 1     3
```

Comment: This works at last. Thank you! I really want to figure out why this works, so my only question, which sounds very silly, is the argument(replace_na(.x, 0) ==7. Would you mind to explain a bit further of this argument? Is that any NA value is replaced with 0?

Comment: @YYM17 it does replace all the NAs with 0, but only when checking to see if the valus is equal to 7 or not. Otherwise, instead of True/False, it would return NA. The NA values in the dataframe will not be affected by `replace_na`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a little helper function that finds the first 7 and replace all values after it with 7. For example

```
carry_forward <- function(x, value=7) {
  start <- first(which(x==value), default = 0)
  if (start == 0) return(x)
  x[start:length(x)] <- value
  x
}
```

And then apply it to all your columns

```
dd %>% 
  mutate(across(A:D, ~ carry_forward(.x, 7)), .by=ID)
```

to get

```
   ID A B  C D Cycle
1 101 7 0 NA 7     1
2 101 7 0  7 7     2
3 101 7 1  7 7     3
4 102 0 0 NA 1     1
5 102 0 0  0 0     2
6 102 0 5  0 1     3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! But I got error like: Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(A:D, ~carry_forward(.x, 7))`.
ℹ In group 1: `ID = 101`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `A`.
Caused by error in `if (start == 0) ...`:
! argument is of length zero

Comment: @YYM17 I tried MrFlick's code, and it worked for me, as they've shown in their answer (with the dataset provided in your question). Please share an example data that would reproduce this error.

Comment: @M-- not sure if it's because my data was arranged previously. I have added a new dataset

Comment: I tried with the the updated example using `dd %>% mutate(across(\`7B\`:\`6D\`, ~ carry_forward(.x, 7)), .by=ID)` and it seemed to work just fine for me.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for the help! Maybe it's something in my previous code. I still get the error message about across and if argument. I can't find out why. But anyway, thank you so much!